# Можно ли так сказать: "И зима в анонсе"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, фразеология

"И зима в анонсе ...". Так можно сказать?

Answer (score 1):

Нет такого слова "ононс", но есть АНОНС - публичное оповещение о каком-либо событии (концерте,спектакле, показе кинофильма). В прямом смысле фраза странная, а в переносном вполне возможна, даже образна: И зима в близком будущем.

Answer (score 1):

Это, имхо, немного неблагозвучно, но если по тексту подразумевается, что нечто анонсирует скорый приход зимы (то есть чувствуется ее скорое приближение), то "зима" вполне может быть "в анонсе".